# Exporting a class and its methods in GWT for use in native JavaScript

Tags: gwt, gwt-exporter

I'm developing a GWT project at the moment and it's been up and running for a while. New functionality that is to be added require extensive testing, visualizing and simulating of a specific algorithm. I would like to export that specific algorithm so that I may call it directly from JavaScript and do some canvas magic.

***How can I export a number of classes for direct use in JavaScript from a GWT project?***

I've tried using the [GWT exporter](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/), following the [Getting Started](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/wiki/GettingStarted) section closely.
I've noticed that my output directory contains a new generator class (TestClassExporterImpl.java) but the final JavaScript output contains no trace of my TestClass or the exported methods.
I'm sure I've made a mistake somewhere on the way or didn't understand the GWT exporter correctly.

Comment: Did you try calling your JS objects in the JavaScript console? So from their example, you'll type: new com.example.Person('manolo')

Comment: Hm, it seems the exported functionality is only provided at runtime. Calling the functions from the console works like a charm even though there's no trace of it in the JavaScript files themselves. If you provide it as an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable obfuscation, it will create the same names in Javascript as in the original Java code